# The use of asterisk in FQDN

Tags: fqdn

Hi I am trying to find the duplicate objects of a Fortigate and I am seeng that we have some fqdns defined for example as *.google.com and other defined as api.google.com. Does the register with asterisk take into account the other fqdn?
Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved the doubt. The one without asterisk is more restrictive so they are not the same, it wouldnt make sense to remove that object. Nevertheless, Normally when you want to enable a FQDN you would want to allow all the extensions of that fqdns; for example, if you want to allow .maps.google.com and other services of google it would be better to allow *.google.com. Despite of this, a lot of people want to have a more granularized network filtering.